# Will extra lines in JS can affect efficiency

Tags: javascript

All:

I am new to Javascript, one question is:

If I add a lot of blank line to  javascript file(to separate logical code block),  will those lines affect the efficiency of execution (like V8 will take more time to run it)?

Thanks

Comment: Nope. Just more time to download. However, if you want multiple breaks to separate logical code blocks, maybe you should place them in separate files.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks, so it will affect the size of file though.

Comment: Right. The file size will increase but execution time will be the same as if you didn't have those blank lines in there.

Comment: The file size will increase, but not by much. I just created a js file containing 5000 line breaks and nothing else. It is 10kB. I don't think you'll have that many blank lines, so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

The browser parses the whole Javascript file before it's executed, and whitespace is mostly ignored. However, as this will make the file itself larger, the load time for the Javascript file will go up.

That being said, the usual approach when making production code is to minify (remove all unnessesary whitespace, etc.) source files before putting them on a live server. There are [Python Extensions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsmin), [Online Tools](http://jscompress.com/), and even some CMS/server system that handle it automatically.

So, format your code to be human legible, then just minify it.

Answer (score 1):

No, It does not depend on blank spaces or comments you use in your code to make it understandable.